# Trying create multuple table using LIKE from multiple tables as source using arrays

Tags: mysql

I have two base tables `"tutorials_tb2","tutorials_tbl"`
and I am trying to create two new tables from these tables as `"tutorials_tb2_new","tutorials_tbl_new"`
So `tutorials_tb2` will be source to `tutorials_tb2_new` and similarly `tutorials_tbl` to `tutorials_tbl_new`

I am trying by creating a MySQL function with new and orig tables as array by using `JSON_*` methods

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION example()
BEGIN
  
DECLARE _counter INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE _value varchar(50);

SET @origTables = '["tutorials_tb2","tutorials_tbl"]';
SET @newTables = '["tutorials_tb2_new","tutorials_tbl_new"]';

WHILE _counter < JSON_LENGTH(@origTables) DO

CREATE TABLE JSON_VALUE(@newTables, CONCAT('$[',_counter,']')) LIKE JSON_VALUE(@origTables, CONCAT('$[',_counter,']'))
SET _counter = _counter + 1;

END WHILE;
END //

DELIMITER ;

SELECT example();
```

And while executing I am getting below error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN

DECLARE _counter INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE _value varchar(50);

SET @origT' at line 2
MySQL>
```

Comment: Tablename is literal, not expression. Use PREPARE (dynamic SQL).

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your syntax error is that a stored function requires a `RETURNS <type>` clause before the `BEGIN`. Review the syntax documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html

The next problem you will encounter, as Akina commented above, is that the JSON expression returns a string, not an identifier. You can't `CREATE TABLE <string-expression>` and have the result of the expression be the table name.

You would have to interpolate the string expression into a string, and execute that string as a dynamic SQL statement. But you can't do that in a stored function.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html#stored-routine-sql-restrictions says:

> SQL prepared statements (PREPARE, EXECUTE, DEALLOCATE PREPARE) can be used in stored procedures, but not stored functions or triggers. Thus, stored functions and triggers cannot use dynamic SQL (where you construct statements as strings and then execute them).

Really, you are making this task much harder than it should be by using stored functions and JSON.

Just write an app or a script that loops over the table names you want to create, format the DDL statement as a string including the table name, then execute the DDL statement.

Here's an example in Python:

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(...)

cursor = cnx.cursor()

for tablename in ["tutorials_tb2","tutorials_tbl"]:
    sql = f"CREATE TABLE `{tablename}_new` LIKE `{tablename}`"
    cursor.execute(sql)

cnx.close()
```

I hardly ever use stored routines or JSON in MySQL.